# Form One way binding with vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my application, I use a 2 way binding with vuex:

```
  messageContent: {
    get () {
      return store.getters.messageContent
    },
    set (value) {
      store.commit('updateContent', value)
    }
  },

<b-form-textarea id="content" v-model="messageContent" :rows="3"></b-form-textarea>

<b-button size="sm" variant="primary" value="Cancel" aria-label="Cancel" @click.prevent='onCancel'>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel
   </b-button>
```

Since mutation of the prop occurred already, if I click cancel edit button:

```
 methods: {
      onCancel () {
        this.isEdit = !this.isEdit
      }
 }
```

how do I rollback?

I figured one way is the solution, but I'm not sure how to implementation it with vuex.

Comment: Can you add the html part with the input with binded messageContent and cancel edit button?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Hm. Directive `v-model` is not very appropriate in this situation. To be able to create "undo", you need clearly distinguish between old value - before typing / editing text-area and new value - value to "save". So, what do you mean with this "cancel edit" button? Returning to value before text-area gets the focus?

Comment: by cancel, I mean returning the view to the previous state or read only view.

Comment: And where do you hold this previous state?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to find out. How to implement the rollback to previous state.

Comment: See an example in answer whether is it what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like in this example, you need to clearly distinguish what is old content - old state and what new content - new state. Something, as this is simplified, yet working example.

```js
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    savedContent: 'Previous content'
  },
  mutations: {
    saveContent (state, value) {
      state.savedContent = value
    }
  }
})

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: {
    newContent: store.state.savedContent
  },
  methods: {
    save () {
      this.$store.commit('saveContent', this.newContent)
    },
    cancel () {
      this.newContent = this.$store.state.savedContent
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="newContent"></textarea><br>
  <button @click="save">save</button>
  <button @click="cancel">cancel</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Works until `savedContent` typeof !== Object